# ¿Por que PHP ignora una linea de código?

Tags: php, redirección, lógica

He desarrollado un sistema de LogIn que funciona casi por completo, salvo un pequeño detalle, y es que parece que PHP esta ignorando una linea de redirección

```
header("Location: index.php?inactivo");
```

Intente buscar en el manual de PHP pero no logre encontrar nada en concreto.

Aquí pongo el código con las debidas anotaciones para explicar el funcionamiento linea a linea.

```
<?php
// Llama la funcion de conexión
require("conexion.php");
// Inicio la clase heredando los metodos de conexion
class loginConexion extends conexion{
    // Creo el metodo constructor
    public function __construct(){
        //ejecuto el metodo constructor heredado
        parent::__construct();
    }
    // Creo el metodo para verificar el login
    public function verificaLogin(){
        // Creo la consulta SQL
        $sql="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario";
        // Preparo la consulta
        $resultado=$this->conexion_db->prepare($sql);
        // Obtengo los valores provinientes del formulario Login
        $usuario=$_POST["usuario"];
        $password=$_POST["password"];
        // Ejecuto la sentencia
        $resultado->execute(array("usuario"=>$usuario));
        // Creo una variable para contar los registros con usuario y contraseña correcto (Debe 1 para entrar)
        $contador=0;
        /* Ejecuto el bucle hasta concluir con el array obtenido de la consulta
        Si encuentra almenos un registro que coninsida con un usuario registrado
        entrara en el bucle */
        while($registro=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            // Verifico que el usuario y la contraseña sean correctos
            if(password_verify($password,$registro['password'])){
                /* Si los datos son correctos, verifico que el usuario este activado
                con la variable $registro["status"] (Valor obtenido de la base de datos: 1 Activado, 0 Desactivado)*/
                if($registro["status"]==1){
                    // Si el usuario esta activado, incremente la variable contador
                    $contador++;
                }
                else{
                    // En caso de que el usuario no este activo lo redirecciono al idex adjuntando un valor GET

                    header("Location: index.php?inactivo"); /* <--- ESTA LINEA NO ESTA SIENDO EJECUTADA 
                                                                    COMO SI EL PROGRAMA LA IGNORARA 
                                                                    ESTA ES MI DUDA*/

                }
            }
        }
        // Verifico si el contador fue incrementado anteriormente
        if($contador>0){
            // Si el contador fue incrementado inicio una session
            session_start();
            // Creo una variable de session para la validacion del resto de paginas
            $_SESSION["identificado"]=true;
            // Lo redirecciono al sitio para usuarios
            header("Location: usuariosRegistrados.php");
        }
        else{
            /* En caso de no coinsidir en el nombre de usuario o contraseña
            lo redirecciono al index.php con un valor GET */
            header("Location: index.php?error");
        }
    }
}
// Creo el objeto instanciando la clase loginConexion
$conectar=new loginConexion();
// Ejecuto el metodo verificaLogin
$conectar->verificaLogin();
?>
```

El sistema ingresa si el usuario y contraseña son correctos, Redirecciona al index con el valor Error en la URL, pero NO Redirecciona con un valor inactivo en la URL si se trata de un usuario desactivado.

He revisado la logica y parece que esta bien, ¿Que esta pasando, que estoy ignorando, tiene que ver algo con el While?

PD: He resuleto el problema cambiado un poco el código, sin embargo me queda la duda de lo que esta pasando.

Comment: Hola, lo que estás haciendo ahí es enviarle una variable por GET al archivo index, pero no le estás pasando ningún valor, un ejemplo **destino.php?variable1=valor1**, creo que por ahi puede estar el error. Saludos

Comment: No, el problema no es ese, mando el valor vacio solo para que dentro del index verifique si existe la variable GET y muestre un mensaje de acuerdo al nombre valor enviado.

Comment: Pero, ¿esto lo imprime en pantalla: `echo "Estoy dentro del ELSE de usuario Desactivado";`? ¿...?

Comment: Ya borre el echo, como estaba originalmente @A.Cedano

Comment: Yo quisiera ver el resultado de `var_dump($registro);` inmediatamente después de haber sido creado. Además tu código es muy pero que muy raro, hace redirecciones dentro de un `while` y cosas así, ¿por qué? Si el bucle debe terminar cuando esa condición se cumpla es mejor hacer un `break` y luego redirigir. Creo que tienes el código mal organizado y luego te enredas con él. Cuando viene a ver ni siquiera hace falta un `while`, no sé, es raro que las cosas deban funcionar así.

Comment: @A.Cedano Creo que el problema no esta ahi, igual y me equivoco, el problema es que no esta redirecionando a index.php?inactivo, curiosamente si borro la linea de casi hasta abajo, header("Location: index.php?error"); Si funciona el primer redireccionamiento, es algo muy extraño, pienso que estoy violando una regla

Comment: No sé si el problema está ahí o no, pero si organizas tu código encontrarás el problema. Como te digo, no es correcto redirigir dentro de un bucle. ¿Por qué haces eso? Está mal hecho, produce código spaghetti. Te recomiendo que seas riguroso en tu programa, terminando lo que tenga que terminar. No deberías salir de un bucle sin más haciendo una redirección. Eso indica un problema de planteamiento que a la larga dificulta encontrar otros problemas en el código. No tienes control sobre tu código y eso es grave.

Comment: Si aceptas mi crítica (constructiva) te daré una técnica que yo suelo usar para las redirecciones: **hago una sola redirección, usando una variable, que voy seteando a todo lo largo del código**, así te obligas a ser riguroso. Se trata de ir recogiendo una variable `$url` y al final de todo el flujo del código hacer algo así: **`header("Location: $url");`** si lo haces así verás que el código es más claro, y detectas cualquier error, por ejemplo, solamente imprimiendo `$url` vas a saber por donde pasó el programa. En tu código, entre tantos `if` y tantas redirecciones uno se pierde.

Comment: @A.Cedano Le agradezco mucho esa critica, al final como me dice he lo resolví, haciendo algo similar a lo que me comenta, creo que al final estoy desarollando de forma incorrecta, voy a poner en practica su consejo, muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Otra cosa es que cuando recibas datos por POST deberías verificar si los mismos no están vacíos, al menos aquellos que son *esenciales*, como llaves primarias de una tabla, o datos destinados a ser usados en una clásula `WHERE`.  La cuestión es que el código debe prever y saber manejar cualquier fallo, cualquier olvido, cualquier descuido del usuario. No se puede programar pensando que siempre el usuario hará las cosas correctamente. Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gracias a la critica de @A. Cedano he reconsiderado el proceso y lo he mejorado, el resultado es correcto, aunque aun podría haber cosas a mejorar.

Siéntanse libres de criticar y corregirme.

```
<?php
// Llama el archivo conexión.php
require("conexion.php");
// Creo la Clase loginConexión heredando la clase conexion
class loginConexion extends conexion{
    // Creo el metodo constructor
    public function __construct(){
        // Ejecuto del metodo constructor de la clase heredada
        parent::__construct();
    }
    // Creo la función verifivaLogin que hara el resto del proceso
    public function verificaLogin(){
        // Declaro la consulta SQL solicitando el usuario
        $sql="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario";
        // Preparo la consulta
        $resultado=$this->conexion_db->prepare($sql);
        /* Obtengo los valores de POST y los asigno a las variables
        Los campos contienen un valor asegurado desde el formulario HTML
        con el argumento: requiere */
        $usuario=$_POST["usuario"];
        $password=$_POST["password"];
        // Ejecuto la consulta
        $resultado->execute(array(":usuario"=>$usuario));
        /* Creo una variable contador, que se usara como auxiliar
        para verificar el login */
        $contador=0;
        // Ejecuto el array para con las coinsidencias obtenidas de la consulta
        while($registro=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            // Verifico la contraseña
            if(password_verify($password,$registro['password'])){
                // Incremento el contador
                $contador++;
                // Genero Variables para identificar si el usuario esta activado
                // y si se trata de un administrador
                $estado=$registro["status"];
                $tipo=$registro["tipo"];
            }
        }
        // Verifico si el contador incremento, significa que el usario y contraseña son correctos
        if($contador>0){
            // Verifico que la cuenta este activada
            if($estado==1){
                // Inicio session
                session_start();
                /* Creo la variable de session indentificado para las paginas 
                para usuarios registrados */
                $_SESSION["identificado"]=true;
                // Verifico si se trata de un administrador
                if($tipo=="admin"){
                    /* Creo la variable de session admin para las paginas 
                    exclusivas de administradores */
                    $_SESSION["tipo"]="admin";
                    // Asigno la URL a la que voy a redireccionar al administrador
                    $url="admin.php";
                }
                // Si el usuario no es administrador
                else{
                    // Asigno la URL a la que se redireccionara
                    $url="formRegistros.php";
                }
            }
            // Si la cuenta no esta activada
            else{
                /* Asigno la URL a la que se redireccionara con valor en GET
                para generar un mensaje de "Falata activación" */
                $url="index.php?inactivo";
                //echo "Estoy en Inactivo";
            }
        }
        // Si el contador no incremento: Usuario o contraseña incorrecta
        else{
            /* Asigno la URL a la que se redireccionara con valor en GET
                para generar un mensaje de "Usuario o Contraseña incorrectos" */
            $url="index.php?error";
            //echo "Estoy en Error";
        }
        // Devuelvo el valor de la variable $url
        return $url;
    }
}
// Creo el objeto principal
$conectar=new loginConexion();
// Llamo la funcion verificaLogin y espero la $url como respuesta
$url=$conectar->verificaLogin();
// realizo el redireccionamiento con la url obtenida
header("Location: $url");
?>
```